# How is a C function pointer laid out in memory

Tags: c, memory, runtime, c99

There's some information about how struct is laid out in memory in a C process. I wanted to know how a function pointer is laid out in memory.
e.g.

```c
void (*fun_ptr)(int)
```

Comment: this is a variable which contains an address of a first instruction in the function suitable for a 'call' command. So, depend on your system, it is 34/64/... byte long.

Comment: Just like any other pointer. The Interpretation is different.

Comment: @Serge You mean 32/64/...?

Comment: is there a reference for this? Would like to check memory layout of other data types too.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It would be a pointer to some location in memory. How is it laid out there? Does it point to some address in the text section of the process memory layout?

Comment: Exact layout depends on the compiler and on the operating system configuration, relative location of the target, .... You can disassemble your code and check assembler instructions for this, check compiler documentation/forums or compiler source code.

Comment: A structure is composed of data. An instance of a structure has a definite memory address. A function is composed of machine instructions. An instance of a function has a definite memory address. Does this help you picture how a function might be "laid out in memory"?

Comment: A function pointer is a number, which is the address of the function.

Comment: @Serge: “Pointers to functions” are not always the address of the first instruction (or, more properly, the address of the entry point). In some systems, they are the address of a function descriptor, which may contain information about parameters and other information, including the address of the entry point.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely a function of the underlying platform.  C does not specify the representation of any pointer type, only what its behavior needs to be.

C *does* specify that object and function pointers are not interchangeable; a `void *` can be converted to any *object* pointer type and vice-versa, and a function pointer type can be converted to any other function pointer type, but converting between object and function pointers may not be allowed (`gcc` with the `-pedantic` flag will yak if you try to convert a function pointer to `void *` or vice-versa).

Pointers may have a simple flat integer representation, or they may be a structured representation like a page number and an offset, or they may be something else.  Pointers to different types don't have to have the same size and representation - e.g., a `char *` doesn't have to have the same representation as an `int *`, which doesn't have to have the same representation as a `struct foo *`, etc.

But again, it depends entirely on the platform.